# approaching attribute in django auth.user model extension

Tags: django

```
#models.py

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I extended the django.contrib.auth.views.models.User with additional infomations such as birthday etc.
The problem is that I can't access `birthday` with `request.user.profile` in the `views.py`.
I had to use extra widget to make the app more intuitive.

I did it like this :

```
#forms.py
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo', 'phone_num', 'nationality', 'gender')

#views.py
@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance = request.user,
                                 data = request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance = request.user.profile,
                                       data = request.POST,
                                       files = request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            request.user.profile.birthday = user_form.cleaned_data['birthday']
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(
            instance = request.user.profile
        )
    return render(request,
                  'views/edit_profile.html',
                  {'user_form' : user_form,
                   'profile_form' : profile_form})
```

The full traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fac3cbfa488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/bravepeach/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'', include('webapp.urls')),
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/webapp/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/webapp/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserEditForm, ProfileEditForm
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/webapp/forms.py", line 37, in <module>
    class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/peterkim/PycharmProjects/brave/bravepeach_web/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 257, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (birthday) specified for User
```

Comment: The traceback shows that the error is in `UserEditForm`, which you haven't shown. If that form is for the `User` model, then it shouldn't contain the `birthday` field because it's from the `Profile` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alasdair mentioned, you need to correct your UserEditForm class. Coming back to custom widget you can do

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo', 'phone_num', 'nationality', 'gender', 'birthday')
        widgets = {
            'birthday': extras.SelectDateWidget,
        }
```